# What are differents between foo().collect{...} and launch { foo().collect{...} }?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

The Code A get the Result A, and the Code B get the Result B .

1: Is the `fun foo()` coroutines ? why doesn't it add keyword `suspend` before if it's a coroutines function?

2: In my mind, a coroutines function is fired using `launch {...}` or `aync {...}` if `fun foo()` is a coroutines function, why can the `main()` fun in Code B invoke it directly?

3: What are differents between Code A and Code B ?

**Code A**

```
fun main() = runBlocking<Unit> {    
    launch {
        for (k in 1..3) {
            println("I'm not blocked $k")
            delay(100)
        }
    }

    launch {
       foo().collect { value -> println(value) } 
    }   
}


fun foo(): Flow<Int> = flow { 
    for (i in 1..3) {
        delay(100) 
        emit(i+5) 
    }
}
```

**Result A**

```
I'm not blocked 1
I'm not blocked 2
6
I'm not blocked 3
7
8
```

**Code B**

```
fun main() = runBlocking<Unit> {    
    launch {
        for (k in 1..3) {
            println("I'm not blocked $k")
            delay(100)
        }
    }

    foo().collect { value -> println(value) } 

}


fun foo(): Flow<Int> = flow { 
    for (i in 1..3) {
        delay(100) 
        emit(i+5) 
    }
}
```

**Result B**

```
I'm not blocked 1
6
I'm not blocked 2
7
I'm not blocked 3
8
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `foo` function is not a suspending function, so you can call it outside a coroutine scope. This function builds a flow and returns the flow, but the flow does not start.
The flow only starts when you call `collect` on it, and that is a suspending function, so calling `collect` must be done in a coroutine scope.
`flow`s are  cold, they only start emitting items when you call `collect` on them, so building the flow is not a suspending function because it's a fast operation.

Comment: Thanks!  Why  is `delay(100)` added the  `fun foo()`? In my mind, only   suspend  functin can use `delay()`.

Comment: That delays the emission of items in the flow. This code runs only after you call collect, so this will run in a coroutine scope. Keep in mind that building and collecting a flow are two very different things.

Answer (score 3):

> 1: Is the fun foo() coroutines ? why doesn't it add keyword suspend before if it's a coroutines function?

Actually `foo()` is a regular function that returns a Flow.

> 2: In my mind, a coroutines function is fired using launch {...} or aync {...} if fun foo() is a coroutines function, why can the main() fun in Code B invoke it directly?

Also using `runBlocking{...}`, `runBlockingTest{...}`, `produce{...}` and `actor{...}`.
It doesn't matter where you build/create/declare a Flow, what matters is where you call  terminal operators (like `collect`) which are suspending functions and must be called inside a coroutine or inside another suspending function. Btw, you're running all the main method inside a coroutine since you're wrapping it inside a `runBlocking` block.

> 3: What are differents between Code A and Code B ?

None. You're just creating another coroutine on Code A which will also run on the main thread.